# Near Protocol: Error during Context.predecessor in view

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to get sender accountId in contract and getting error.

My contract:

```
@nearBindgen
export class Contract {
  private message: string = 'Hello '

  helloWorld(): string {
    const predecessor = Context.predecessor
    return this.message + predecessor
  }
}
```

I'm trying to access contract from CLI with following command(with my account id):

```
near view $CONTRACT helloWorld --accountId <id>.testnet
```

Error:

```
Error: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(ProhibitedInView { method_name: "predecessor_account_id" })).
```

Comment: Oops. I should use near call instead of near view

Answer (score 4):

Oops. I should use

```
near call
```

instead of

```
near view
```

Comment: yep, see more here https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro#potential-gotchas